# Suma pares, producto impares, error resultado impares

Tags: java

Acabo de realizar un ejercicio bastante simple en el cual realizo la suma de los veinte primeros números pares y el producto de los veinte primeros números impares, la suma de los pares la tengo realizada de forma correcta, sin embargo, al realizar la multiplicación de los números impares, sigue multiplicando dándome muchos más números extraños, cuando debe terminar supuestamente en el resultado 654729075, ya que multiplica los 20 primeros números impares. Dejo el código por aquí. Un saludo y aprecio la explicación de quien consiga ver el error, muchas gracias.

```
public class sum_divide 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int suma = 0;
        int producto = 1;
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                suma = suma + i;
                System.out.println(suma);    
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 != 0)
            {
                producto = producto * i;
                System.out.println(producto);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, intenta convertir la variable producto a long

Comment: lo q pasa es q tu variable es de tipo int, y este tipo tiene un rango, si el numero se sale de ese rango ya no funciona, debes poner un tipo de datos que admita intervalos numericos mas grandes, quiza long, y BigInteger, este ultimo admite numeros inmensamente grandes, pero su procesamiento es mas lento

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que el tipo de datos **int,** admite números que estén en el intervalo **(-2147483648 a 2147483647)**. Si las operaciones matemáticas que realizas devuelven un valor numérico no comprendido en ese rango entonces la variable donde guardes las operaciones realizadas tomará un valor erróneo, ya que se sale del rango numérico válido.

Debes probar con tipos de datos que admiten intervalos más grandes:

**long:** tiene un intervalo de **-9.223.372.036.854.775.808 a 9.223.372.036.854.775.807**.

Como ves este tipo de datos admite un intervalo más grande, pero igual se quedaría corto en ciertas operaciones matemáticas que involucren números inmensamente grandes(Quizá tu problema se resuelva usando **long**).

Para realizar cálculos con valores enormes, sin que te preocupen intervalos numéricos está la **clase** **BigInteger**.

Usando esta clase tu problema podría resolverse de esta forma:

```
//Solo me concentro en los impares ya que el cálculo de los pares no tiene problema

BigInteger resultado = new BigInteger("1");

for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
{
   if(i % 2 != 0 )
   {
      resultado = resultado.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
      System.out.println(resultado);
   }
 }
```

Aquí se declara una variable de tipo **BigInteger** y se inicializa en **1**, posteriormente se pregunta si el número es impar y se van realizando los cálculos correspondientes y mostrándose por pantalla los resultados obtenidos.

Para usar la **clase** **BigInteger** debes poner en los **imports**:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

Para trabajar con valores de coma flotante puedes usar además el tipo de datos **BigDecimal**.

**Referencia:** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/

Si lo deseas puedes investigar más en Internet.

Comment: Si, con ésto, los primeros 10 impares = 654729075; y los primeros 20 impares  = 319830986772877770815625. Descomunal ;)

Comment: Muy interesante, no conocía el uso de BigInteger, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.